# Noncentrality parameter in two-sample-t-test (Power analysis)

Tags: r, distributions, t-test, statistical-power

I am working with R, doing a post-hoc power analysis.

Can anyone explain to me why these two commands generate different outputs? I thought they should not!

```
> 1-pt(tcrit-nc, df)
[1] 0.4248602
> 1-pt(tcrit, df, ncp=nc)
[1] 0.430632
```

I've got ...

```
n = 18
df = (n-1) * 2 = 34
tcrit = qt(0.05, df, lower = F)
nc = sqrt(n/2)*0.5 = 1.5 # 0.5 is the effect size
```

Edit: I found out, that R uses different algorithms to estimate the probabilities, depending on if the ncp-paramter is set or not. So can anybody confirm that this should be the only reason for the probabilities to differ?

Comment: The non-central t distribution is not some shifted version of t: see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution) for details.